# Unexpected Output Shown by Program in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, error-correction

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void long_fctrl(int num[], int f_num) // Function for Factorial
   {
    --f_num; // Decrement Number to multiply with Factorial Number. 
    int i = 0, pow = 0, x, j, len = 0, k = 0;
    while(f_num > 1) // Loop for Factorial Number
    {
      i = 0;
          do { // Loop to Multiply Two Array Number
            x = (num[i]*f_num) + pow;
            num[i] = x%10;
            pow = x/10;
            ++i;
         }while((pow!=0) || (x == 0));
       --f_num;
      if(k == 0) //Condition to Find the Length of Factorial Number in array
      {
          len = i;
          k = 1;
      }
      if(i > len)// Condition for factorial array Length
        len = i;
    }
     cout << "Your Number : \n";
     for(j = len-1; j >= 0; --j) // Loop for Output of Factorial Number..
        cout << num[j];
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Number (1 - 100) : ";
    int num, temp;
    cin >> num;// num is the number of which we have to calculate Factorial.
    if(num > 0 && num <= 100)
    {
        int fctrl[200] = {0};
        int i;
        temp = num;// Temp initialize to Factorial Number..
        for(i = 0; temp!= 0; ++i,temp/=10) 
        {
             fctrl[i] = temp%10;
        } // Loop to insert user entered Number in Factorial Array...
        long_fctrl(fctrl, num);  //Giving Factorial Number in Array and also
                                 //in the integer form to the Function 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program is to Calculate Factorial with in range 1 to 100 ..
By inputting Number less than 6 it is giving correct Output
**Input :** *5*
**Output :** *120*
But For Other Number it is Giving Wrong Output
**Input :** *9*
**Output :** *8080*
**Expected Output :** *362880*
I am not able to find my logical error ...................
Please, if you are able to find any error , tell me.......
............................................................
.............................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You condition to end your multiply loop (`while((pow!=0) || (x == 0))`) is wrong.  This loop needs to run until i >= len, **and** pow != 0.

In the case of 9, you'll get

```
9
72    * 8
504   * 7
524   * 6
```

because the loop ends after the 24 because pow == 0 and x == 2; the 5 is left over from before.

Comment: I am Not able To Understand .Please answer in detail...and i am initializing len after multiplying loop so how can i use it Before??

Comment: @NavneetC. You need to keep track of len every loop, so you know how long your current number is, so that you know how far your multiplication has to got.  Step thru your code in a debugger, or work thru it on paper, as I've done above.

Answer (score -1):

If your are using C++ IDE such as (Code Block) You should debug your program and check step by step what is going wrong and where.